# If you smoke weed twice a day, does your prayer become invalid for 40 days or 80 days?

Tags: halal-haram, salat, smoking

If someone smokes marijuana 'twice' within a day, will his prayer be not accepted for 40 days or 80 `(= 2 * 40)` days?

Comment: Following that logic, if you smoke marijuana twice a day in 10 days, you would reach 800 days. Does that sound logic?

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: The question is essentially:  Does the spiritual harm from smoking marijuana twice remain twice as long in the body?  Spiritual harm is intangible, and I did not find an answer in ahadith nor fatawa.

---

The relevant hadith appears in various versions: Sunan Ibn Majah [grade: sahih] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/urn/1277380)), Sunan an-Nasa'i [grade: sahih] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/nasai/51/132)), Sunan an-Nasa'i [grade: da'if] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/nasai/51/131)), Sunan an-Nasa'i 5664 [grade: sahih] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/nasai/51/126)), Jami` at-Tirmidhi [grade: da'if] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/26/2)), and Sunan Abi Dawud 3680 [grade: sahih] ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/27/12)).  The latter one states:

> If anyone drinks wine, Allah will not accept prayer from him for forty days, but if he repents, Allah will accept his repentance. If he repeats it a fourth time, it is binding on Allah that He will give him tinat al-khabal to drink.
>
> He was asked: What is tinat al-khabal, Messenger of Allah? He replied: Discharge of wounds, flowing from the inhabitants of Hell.

Fatawa ([SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2014/12/23/smoking-marijuana-are-my-prayers-not-valid-for-40-days/); [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/176545); [Darul Ifta Birmingham](http://daruliftabirmingham.co.uk/salah-after-smoking-marijuana/)) confirm this also applies to smoking marijuana, based on the hadith *Every intoxicant is Khamr and every intoxicant is forbidden.* -- Sahih Muslim 2003 a ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/36/92)).

(However, Qibla.com, sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/35738) has a different stance: "The sinfulness of smoking marijuana does not affect the validity of one’s prayers.")

In the context of alcohol (but which should apply likewise to marijuana) [AskMufti.co.za](http://askmufti.co.za/harms-of-alcohol/) writes:

> It can be gauged from this Hadeeth that the effect (spiritual harm) of alcohol remains in the body for forty days.

So the question becomes: *Does the spiritual harm from smoking marijuana twice remain twice as long in the body?*

Spiritual harm is intangible.  If we were to ask the same for physical harm *do two cuts take twice as long to heal as one cut?* the answer would probably be "it depends on the cuts".  We also encounter a divisibility problem, e.g. *do two small joints count the same as one large joint?*.

I did not find an answer in the above ahadith nor fatawa.  This makes me think the answer to this question is unclear except to Allah.

Answer (score -1):

It has nothing to do with the quantity---just time. Once 40 days are up since you last smoked, your prayers will be answered. But don’t mind that, because either way we are all still obligated to pray during that 40 day period.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE, on StackExchange we have a [be nice](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy, please consider elaborating your post and explaining your point in a few more words (see [answer]),

Answer (score -1):

Really funny question I really laughed a lot :D :D 
The "prayer is invalid for 40 days" is to stress on how aweful and unacceptable smoking weed is in Islam, to emphasize that it should be avoided at all cost. The consequences are so tragic that Allah does not accept your prayers for 40 days (and no one can guarantee you won't die during those 40 days, with Allah angry at your actions that he's not accepting your prayers) The answer is simply don't smoke weed.

I leave you with **my translation** of this story:

> A man came to the prophet (peace be upon him) and asked him: 
>    - does Allah forgive those who commit zina?
>    - Yes 
>   A few moments later, another man came, and asked:
>    - does Allah forgive those who commit zina?
>    - No
>
> The Sahabas who were present asked the prophet (peace be upon him):
>    - Why did you say `yes` to the first but `no` to the second 
>    - The first one committed zina and wants to repent, but the second one is asking to check whether he can commit zina or not.

Now you're acting like the 2nd guy in the story above.
Allah Knows best.